# How did the Thirty Years War affect Baroque music?

Tags: music, thirty-years-war

The Thirty Years War is situated in time between the end of the Renaissance and the beginning of the early Baroque periods in music.  I wonder how this affected composers in Europe at the time.

I have noticed that the early Baroque (1600-1650) does not include many of the "better-known" composers of either the Renaissance or the Baroque periods. It is after Palestrina but before Bach and Vivaldi.  It seems to me to be like a miniature Dark Age where comparatively few great works were written, at least in comparison to what came before and what came after.
As I research important pieces of music from around this time, I keep noticing that there wasn't much going on musically specifically in Europe between 1615-1650.
I'm curious to learn what is known about the effect of the Thirty Years War on music.   Has there been research,  for instance,  on...

1. If fewer people sought careers as composers,
2. If a large number of published works are known to have been destroyed,
3. and if the newer Baroque music has ever been viewed at least in part as a response to the ravages of the war.

Comment: I don't know enough to write an answer. Many composers of the time were employed either as organists at important churches or *Kapellmeister* at various courts, and funding for court orchestras dried up during the war due to the high financial burden of military operations. So *Hofkapellen* (court orchestras) were disbanded or much reduced in size, something that is said to be reflected in the works of Heinrich Schütz, for example.

Comment: Wars do have a way of sucking up resources (including talented young men).

Comment: "I have noticed that the early Baroque (1600-1650) does not include many of the "better-known" composers of either the Renaissance or the Baroque periods." -- This is a matter of opinion, but Monteverdi, Frescobaldi, and Cavalli were *huge* and very influential. For non-Italian composers, Sweelink and Schütz were also important figures. Just because Bach and Vivaldi are more well known today doesn't mean there "wasn't much going on musically."

Comment: [I know it's nitpicking at a few statements, but I believe those nits worth picking at. That said, the question as to how music was affected by the war is a valid one and worth exploring.]

Comment: @cmw that's a very valid nitpick

Comment: Worth asking a version of this on music se as well imo

Comment: @LukeSawczak yes, possibly, although I think it a more valid question on this site